# wordpress plugin textarea post generte '\\' automatically

Tags: javascript, wordpress, post, plugins, textarea

i tried to add form in normal php code like alert("test ");
and save it than it shows it same as i entered in text area

```
<?php echo $_POST['txt'];?>
<form name="frm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="txt"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="sub" />
</form>
```

how ever when i does the same thing in wordpress the port retruns me alert(\"test ");
every time i save it the slashes increase like `alert(\\"test "\\);`
is there any way to prevent it via any php code ?

Comment: show your full code.. so it better to understand...

Comment: hmmm .. I have seen this problem before in action . unfortunately not the solution. have you tried to stack some kind of stripslash function like http://magp.ie/2011/01/20/addslashes-and-stripslashes-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

some how i use and workd for me remove whites space and slashes from string

```
$_POST['txt']= trim(urldecode(stripslashes($_POST['txt'])));
```